# Pandas: How can I replace all the zeroes within 15,000 columns with the group mean per column?

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have two groups, 0 and 1, under a column named 'group_label' under index location 1, and another ~15000 columns under index locations 6:14844. I would like to replace the 0s in those 15,000 columns, and not the class column, with the class mean. I tried one of the suggestions below but it did not work for me. This is the most current code I have so far:

```
df = df.mask(df.iloc[:, np.r_[1, 6:14844]].eq(0), df.iloc[:, np.r_[1, 6:14844]].groupby('group_label').transform('mean'))
```

This replaces my columns with the group mean, but it also writes over the columns I do not want to write over (1:5) with NaNs

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really recommend not to rely on the column order and magic numbers such as 6 and 14844. If you want to affect certain columns, look at `df.columns` and maybe filter things out of there, á la `data_cols = [c for c in df.columns if c not in ("not_data_1", "not_data_2", ...)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
group_means = df.groupby("group-label").mean()

for group in group_means.index:
    for col in group_means.columns:
        df.loc[(df["group-label"] == group) & (df[col] == 0), col] = group_means.loc[group, col]
```

does what you want.

There might be a more Pandas way to do that...